# Apple watch : Change status bar tint color programmatically

Tags: statusbar, tint, apple-watch

How can I change the global tint / tint color of status bar for a particular `WKInterfaceController` programmatically ?

Answer (score 7):

The documentation says:

> An app’s key color is stored in the Global Tint property of the app’s storyboard. To access this property, select your storyboard and display the File inspector. Select one of several preexisting colors from the popup menu or use the color picker to specify a custom color.

For that reason, it looks like you can only change the global tint color from your Storyboard file.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is not possible to change the tint color programmatically. However Apple's Reminders app does change the title color for each list. They are probably using private API. :-(